# Is it possible to use GAN for filling only the missing part of image instead of generating whole image?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to use GAN for filling the missing part of images using SSIM as a loss function. filling is good but when i find the difference between the actual and predicted output, its shows the same missing portion in the difference image. I want the pixel value difference of actual and predicted image is minimum as possible.

Image pixel range is from -7000 to 180000. i normalize it to [0,1].

Is any solution to improve  it?

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed possible with GAN. In fact filling missing parts of an image is one of the coolest applications of GAN. You may find exactly what you need under the topic **Image inpainting** of this excellent [article](https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/gan-some-cool-applications-of-gans-4c9ecca35900) on GAN applications.

You could find the implemented Image Inpainting code here.
https://github.com/pathak22/context-encoder

You may have a huge (at least in order of 10000s) complete image dataset though.
The loss function I would suggest is the following, where it could create a battle between the generator(G) and discriminator(D).

```
def loss_func(logits_in,labels_in):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=logits_in,labels=labels_in))


G = generator(z)
D_output_real,D_logits_real=discriminator(real_images)
D_output_fake,D_logits_fake=discriminator(G,reuse=True)

D_real_loss=loss_func(D_logits_real,tf.ones_like(D_logits_real)*0.94) #Smoothing for generalization
D_fake_loss=loss_func(D_logits_fake,tf.zeros_like(D_logits_real))
D_loss=D_real_loss+D_fake_loss

G_loss= loss_func(D_logits_fake,tf.ones_like(D_logits_fake))
```

However, the GANs are extremely computationally expensive. As the battle between the generator and discriminator could last even for weeks to have the result you want, specially if the image resolution is high. Just to give you some clue, a GAN that I ran on my RTX 2080 Ti GPU for image generation ran 3 weeks to give acceptable results with 200000 of (218,160) sized images.

So have patience and good luck.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i have  a 1024*512 size image with around 1024*8 masking portion. GAN able to fill the image completely but i want to minimize the diff. b/w actual and predicted. let me try this. Thank you

Comment: More recently, [GPT-3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6Xn4nKm-Qw&ab_channel=TwoMinutePapers) was also demonstrated to solve this problem.